# React Native activeTintColor not getting applied on selected drawer item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

React Native activeTintColor not getting applied on selected drawer item. My react native navigation routes looks like,

```
-> DrawerNavigator
   -> StackNavigator
      -> HomeScreen
      -> FirstScreen
      -> SecondScreen
      -> ThirdScreen
```

`routes.js`

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    ChapterGroup: { screen: ChapterGroupScreen },
    Chapter: { screen: ChapterScreen },
  }

const DrawerStack = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: RootStack,
      params: { id: 1 }
    },
    Kural: { screen: ChapterGroupScreen, params: { id: 2 } },
    Detail: { screen: ChapterGroupScreen, params: { id: 3 } }
  }, { contentComponent: DrawerComponent}
}
export default DrawerStack;
```

I managed to display the First, Second, thirdScreens on the sidebar by creating a new DrawerComponent which will navigate to the appropriate stack screen on drawer item click.

`DrawerComponent.js`

```
resetStack = route => {
 let pressedDrwaerItem = route.route.key;
 let id = route.route.params.id;
 this.props.navigation.dispatch(
   StackActions.reset({
    index: 1,
    actions: [
      NavigationActions.navigate({
        routeName: "Home"
      }),
      NavigationActions.navigate({
        routeName: "ChapterGroup",
        params: { title: pressedDrwaerItem, no: id }
      })
    ]
  })
);
}

render() {
      return (<ScrollView>
              <DrawerItems
              {...this.props}
              onItemPress={this.resetStack}
            </DrawerItems</ScrollView>)
    }
```

It properly gets navigated to the ChapterGroup Screen on Home stack but the drawer activeitem points to the `Home` not the second or third custom name. I think it may be because all the other screen exists inside the Rootstack. Is there anyway to manually set the second drawer item as active?

or any successful implementation of `DrawerNavigator` inside `StackNavigator` ? ie. I want to use two screens from stack navigator as drawer items. And if we navigated through to that particular screen from home screen, the corresponding drawer item should be selected.

Comment: If you try to navigate to "ChapterGroup" then the second screen won't be active. You can navigate to "Kural" and use params to differentiate between those screens is it possible for you to restructure?

Comment: Which `react-navigator` version is it?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure whether you have tried `contentOptions` or not, but this is what i have found from react-navigation document

[contentOptions for DrawerItems](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html#contentoptions-for-draweritems)

There are various property you can use with contentOptions

```
contentOptions: {
  activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
  itemsContainerStyle: {
    marginVertical: 0,
  },
  iconContainerStyle: {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

From above snippet i guess for you `activeTineColor` might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your intentions with the `resetStack` function.

If you use the following function instead, it's going to work:

```
navigateToScreen = (route) => {
  const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
    routeName: route.route.key
  });
  this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
}

//...
<DrawerItems
  {...this.props}
  onItemPress={this.navigateToScreen}>
</DrawerItems>
```

It sets the new screen without stacking it up. It sets the `activeTintColor` though.

I omitted the params passing to make it simple.

Comment: this worked for me in and complex router config, switch > drawer > bottomTabBar